# .htaccess manipulate url (remove items form url) then redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am completely stumped with how to use .htaccess and I have an issue where I;ve migrated my website from one platform(joomla) to another(wordpress).

In doing so I have lost connection to older links

Here is an example of an older link

http://website.com/home/kimberly-wallace-releases-a-delicious-childrens-book-grandmas-chocolate-cake-.html

I want to use .htaccess to remove "/home" and "-.html" . Then redirect to the modified url being

http://website.com/kimberly-wallace-releases-a-delicious-childrens-book-grandmas-chocolate-cake

I would really appreciate any  input ---THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for that URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/(.*).html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

If you have other URL's in different formats, then you'd need to write more Rules.